# Memory Locations of variables with same name

Tags: javascript

```
(function(spanishGreeting, name){
    var spanishGreeting = 'HOLA!!';
    spanishGreeting = 'Como estas!'
    console.log(spanishGreeting);
}(greeting,'John'));
```

Can someone please explain to me if my understanding of the above code is correct?

So first inside the IIFE `var spanishGreeting = 'HOLA!!';` this line of code creates a whole new variable with the same name as the parameter that is passed into the IIFE. So will this new variable declaration overwrite the variable that is passed in as a parameter? So essentially the passed in variable, `spanishGreeting` will be ignored in the rest of the function.

Now is the parameter variable `spanishGreeting` still present in memory? Or has the new variable declaration: `var spanishGreeting = 'HOLA!!';` overwritten the memory location of the parameter variable `spanishGreeting`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now is the parameter variable spanishGreeting still present in memory?

Yes it is still present in memory.  This line:

```
var spanishGreeting = 'HOLA!!';
```

creates a new local variable that shadows/hides the argument by the same name.  It is still possible to access the `spanishGreeting` argument with `arguments[0]`.  The argument variable is still there - you've just shadowed the name so you can't access it by name.

And, this line:

```
spanishGreeting = 'Como estas!'
```

is just assigning a new value to the local variable that the previous line just created.  It does not change the argument variable at all.

In general, you should avoid naming arguments and local variables with the same name because it will just confuse someone reading your code.

> So will this new variable declaration overwrite the variable that is
>   passed in as a parameter?

No.  The new variable declaration overrides the name, but does not replace the argument variable itself.  It can still be accessed via `arguments[0]`.  Naming in Javascript is hierarchical.  The closest scoped names resolve first - if not found there, Javascript looks up the chain to higher places in the chain.  Local variables are the first place it looks, then argument names, then variables in the next scope up and so on and then finally to global variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer!! It cleared up a lot of questions I had haha...!!